# How to serve ads on different urls?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, ads

I want to show ads on other website from my server. I will supply ad code and then control from my server what kind and size of ads should be shown on other pages. other pages will be on other domain and servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many packages out there that will do this, such as openx: http://www.openx.com/publisher/open-source-ad-server

To create this yourself - your question is probably to broad for this website.

Comment: i have download and install this script. but i want to code this custom. so that i can show adds on other websites of my choice and way.

Comment: In that case, I'd say you're question was way to broad for this website.